# Why did Naruto need to summon his Shadow Clones during his fight with Pain?

Tags: naruto

While fighting Pain, Naruto used his Shadow Clones to store his Sage Mode chakra. Since the clones were at Mount Myoboku, he needed to summon them with a scroll.

A) Why didn't he just release the jutsu to get back the chakra in the clone?

B) Why did he need a scroll? Couldn't he have summoned him with just hand signs?

Comment: I know this title needs to be fixed, but Im not quite sure how to fix it. Krazer is needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer **A**: The one you are saying "releasing" the jutsu with the clone isn't possible. What Naruto trying to do is to release the *[Reverse Summoning](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_Summoning_Technique)* which is a *[Space Time Ninjustsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Space%E2%80%93Time_Ninjutsu)* not the Kage Bunshin.

It is said in the wiki that:

*"all summoning-based techniques are space–time manipulation related, as they warp the targets through a **dimensional void to the summoner's location**. It appears that each specific space-time technique has its own unique dimensional void that no other technique can access."*

That means you can't release technique from another (void) dimension wherein the clones are *like* sealed in a container.

Now to release the reverse summon, well that answers **B**:
You need the signed contract(scroll) which serves as the passage way in order for the user (like Naruto) to release the Reversed Summoning then release the Kage Bunshin.

Comment: However, Myobokuzan doesn't lie in another dimension, because Fukusaku says that they can get there on foot in a month. They use the reverse summoning only for speeding it up.

Comment: Yeah. I agree. I think that is from Naruto Manga Episode 445 But it doesn't says there that it is a *void* dimension.

Comment: The problem is that they are far away, a month traveling and they need to keep focussing to keep the chakra, if naruto released the jutsu al clones would come to him and give him to much sage chakra, the second thing is that naruto indeed released the last clone with the technique release

Comment: WHat i wonder is why Naruto couldn't create and then release a clone right away, with it having the knowledge of having one of the clones gathering sage chakra to release. We know Shadow clones gain the knowledge as well as the original when one releases thanks to Naruto's Rasen-Shuriken Training. The released first clone would inform the 2 gathering sage chakra to have one of them release the shadow clone jutsu.